# ViewPager with Custom PageAdapter, how to use XML file instead of defining layout in java

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I'm programming a quartet game, therefore I need a gallery including all the attibutes of each card. 
I found an example of ViewPager with a custom PagerAdapter: 
http://android-er.blogspot.de/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html

For a simple Gallery view this is pretty nice, but I would like to include a XML file (e.g. of my game activity) instead of defining all layout params explicitly. Thanks for any idea!

Here my adapter class:

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        int numberOfPages = cards.size();

        int[] backgroundcolor = {
                0xFF101010};

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return numberOfPages;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            //select Card on current position from List of cards
            final Card tempCard = cards.get(position);

            //set TextView with deck title
            TextView textView = new TextView(DeckViewActivity.this);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textView.setTextSize(30);
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            textView.setText(tempCard.getTitle() + " (" + String.valueOf(position + 1) + "/" + cards.size() + ")");


            //set ImageView with deckcover
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(DeckViewActivity.this);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams imageParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

            int finalHeight = viewPager.getMeasuredHeight();
            int finalWidth = viewPager.getMeasuredWidth();

            //Load Bitmap from assets
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                inputStream = getAssets().open(tempCard.getPicture());
                imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(inputStream, finalWidth, finalHeight));
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);


            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(DeckViewActivity.this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolor[0]);
            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            layout.addView(textView);
            layout.addView(imageView);

            final int page = position;
            layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }});

            container.addView(layout);
            return layout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `instantiateItem()` method can use a `LayoutInflater` (obtained from your activity via `getLayoutInflater()`) to inflate a layout, rather than setting up the widgets in Java.

Or, if you wrap your layout in a fragment, you can use `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine for me in `instantiateItem()`: `View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.page_viewer_pie, container, false);`